# Get content of textbox which is located in listView WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, textbox

```
<ListView x:Name="listView2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="215" Margin="348,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="275">
    <ListView.View>
          <GridView>
               <GridViewColumn Header="Id" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Id}"/>
               <GridViewColumn Header="Artikelnr" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Artikelnr}"/>
               <GridViewColumn Header="Bezeichnung" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Bezeichnung}"/>
               <GridViewColumn Header="Menge">
                   <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                         <DataTemplate>
                              <TextBox x:Name="textBoxListView1" Width="80" Tag="{Binding Menge}"/>
                         </DataTemplate>
                   </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
               </GridViewColumn>    
           </GridView>
      </ListView.View>
 </ListView>
```

This is my ListView, which contains TextBoxes. So there are as many textboxes as rows. **My question is how can I get the content of these textboxes?**

I already tried this:

```
MyItem clMyItem = new MyItem();
clMyItem = (MyItem)listView2.Items.GetItemAt(zeile);

clArtikel.nId = Convert.ToInt32(clMyItem.Id);
clArtikel.cArtikelnr = clMyItem.Artikelnr;
clArtikel.cBezeichnung = clMyItem.Bezeichnung;
clArtikel.nMenge = clMyItem.Menge;
```

but for `clMyItem.Menge` it only returns a null value, probably because this code only gets the content of the textbox at a status directly after the textbox was created.

Comment: "probably because this code only gets the content of the textbox at a status directly after the textbox was created". So when exactly do you want to get the TextBox value? Probably after some text was entered. Call your code then. As a note, `clMyItem = new MyItem()` is redundant when you immediately assign another value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also try somethin totally different.

Using the [MVVM Pattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh848246.aspx).

Create a `Model` first to hold all you data - lets call it "Bestellung":

```
public class Bestellung
{
    public int ID {get; set;}
    public int ArtikelNummer {get; set;}
    public string Bezeichnung {get; set;}
    public int Menge {get; set;}
}
```

Create a `ViewModel` like to bind your data to your view:

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ObservableCollection<Bestellung> Bestellungen {get; set;} = new ObservableCollection<Bestellung>();

    //Implement INotifyPropertyChanged here
}
```

What you need to do in your XAML is to set the `ItemsSource` to `ItemsSource="{Binding Bestellungen}"` **and** the `DataContext` so the view knows on where to look for the `Bindings`.

```
<ListView ItemsSouce="{Binding Bestellungen}">
<ListView.View>
      <GridView>
           <GridViewColumn Header="Id" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Id}"/>
           <GridViewColumn Header="Artikelnr" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Artikelnr}"/>
           <GridViewColumn Header="Bezeichnung" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Bezeichnung}"/>
           <GridViewColumn Header="Menge">
               <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                     <DataTemplate>
                          <TextBox Width="80" Text="{Binding Menge}"/>
                     </DataTemplate>
               </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
           </GridViewColumn>    
       </GridView>
  </ListView.View>
```

Here you bind your `TextBox` containing "Menge" directrly to the property `Menge` of each item in your ListView.

**Also** you could get rid of all those `x:Name`s because you won't need most of them anymore.

You could do this in `YourWindow.xaml.cs`

```
//Code-Behind of your Window
public class YourWindow : Window
{
    public YourWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = new ViewModel();
    }
}
```

The good thing about this is that you can separate your logic and your view.

---

**That means**: You won't access your textbox anymore - because you don't care if it's a `TextBox`, `TextBlock` or sth. else. Your logic does not need to know what's in your view.

To access and change any property of one of your items you could just do this:

```
//Add 3 pcs to the order
Bestellungen.First(bestellung => bestellung.Id == "010101").Menge += 3;
```

or

```
//Delete an order
Bestellungen.Remove(Bestellungen[2]);
```

The `ObservableCollection` observes your model and will notify the UI once something changed. Your new value should be instantly visible.

Comment: thanks,  that totally solved my problem and also helped understanding MVVM a little bit more.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
int index = listView2.SelectedIndex;
if (index != -1)
{
    MyItem items = (MyItem)listView2.Items.GetItemAt(index);
    if (items != null)
    {
         var textBoxContent = items.Menge;
     }
}
```

The `ItemsSource` of a ListView is an `ObservableCollection` and I Binded here with `Text` Property

```
<DataTemplate>
   <TextBox x:Name="textBox" Width="80" Text="{Binding Menge}"/>
/DataTemplate>
```

make sure you implemented `INotifyPropertyChanged` in your `MyItem` Class to make sure your `Menge` property gets updated:

```
public class MyItem : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _menge = "";
    public String Menge
    {
        get { return _menge; }
        set
        {
            _menge = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public string Artikelnr { get; set; } = "";
    public String Bezeichnung { get; set; } = "";
    public String Id { get; set; } = "";

    #region Inotify
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void RaisePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string property = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
    }
    #endregion
}
```

**Output:**

[image]